# Degree of interpolation polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $x_0, x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be $(n+1)$ pairwise distinct real numbers, and $y_0, y_1,\ldots,y_n$ be $(n+1)$ real numbers. We have know that there exists a unique polynomial $P(x)$ where its degree is not greater than $n$. 
What is the necessary and sufficient condition guaranteeing $P(x)$ has a degree of $n$.

Thank you for all comments and helping.

Comment: Set up a (n+1)x(n+1) system of equations for the coefficients of the polynomial. Then use Cramer's rule to obtain a closed formula for the coefficient of $x^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Newton form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) for the interpolation polynomial,
$$
P(x) = [y_0] + [y_0,y_1](x-x_0) + \cdots + [y_0,\ldots,y_n](x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_{n-1}).
$$
the necessary and sufficient condition is that the last [divided difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences) $[y_0,\ldots,y_n]$ is not zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not cheap to check $[y_0,y_1,\ldots,y_n]\ne 0$. Do you have another simple condition?

Comment: @Blind, you can always interpolate the first $n-1$ points and see if it works for the last one, but this is "expensive" too.

Comment: how about using determinant to check?

Comment: @Blind: I thought your question was a mathematical one, but now that you mention "cheapness", then I think you may be asking the wrong question. In computations you should **never** attempt to compute **numerically** whether some real numbers are exactly equal or not, which is essentially what you're going to have to do here no matter what method you use. That will utterly fail in any reasonable numerical algorithm. If you use symbolic computation, however, then not only will it not be cheap, you can't expect any better unless more is known, such as if $x_{0..n}$ are equally spaced.